# Error when running CMake Ubuntu SDK IDE Setup Wizard

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, cmake, scopes

I'm trying to create a C++ Unity scope the ubuntu SDK IDE. Using the setup wizard I have created my project, but the CMake wizard cannot run CMake. I get the following error:

```
E: Failed to change to directory ‘/var/lib/schroot/chroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf/mnt/Data/Programming/RealTime/UbuntuScope/build-RealTime-UbuntuSDK_for_armhf_GCC_ubuntu_sdk_15_04_vivid-Default’: No such file or directory
I: The directory does not exist inside the chroot.  Use the --directory option to run the command in a different directory.
Command returned 1: schroot -c click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armhf-bf5c34a9-5b6b-4bfa-967d-ab92497c576e --run-session -- env DEB_BUILD_ARCH_CPU=amd64 DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE=arm-linux-gnueabihf DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH=arm-linux-gnueabihf DEB_HOST_ARCH_ENDIAN=little DEB_HOST_ARCH=armhf DEB_BUILD_MULTIARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE=x86_64-linux-gnu DEB_BUILD_ARCH_OS=linux DEB_HOST_ARCH_OS=linux DEB_HOST_ARCH_BITS=32 DEB_BUILD_ARCH_ENDIAN=little DEB_HOST_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnueabihf DEB_BUILD_ARCH_BITS=64 DEB_HOST_GNU_CPU=arm DEB_BUILD_GNU_CPU=x86_64 DEB_BUILD_ARCH=amd64 DEB_BUILD_GNU_SYSTEM=linux-gnu DEB_HOST_ARCH_CPU=arm cmake /home/pieter/Programming/RealTime/UbuntuScope/RealTime '-GCodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles'
```

I can't find anything about this in the ubuntu documentation or tutorials. Does anybody know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my programming projects are stored on a hard drive (mounted in /mnt) and symlinked to my home directory for easy access. Creating the scope project in my home directory solves my problem. I don't know if there is a workaround for this, but the setup wizard definitely doesn't like this.